# Explicitly send url to proxy server during http connect request

Tags: proxy, network-programming

I want to send the requested url to the proxy server during http connect request. The network is behind a proxy server.
For example-: Whenever we watch some video on facebook the header in http connect request that is intercepted at proxy server contains "http://video.fmaa11.fna.fbcdn.net:443" in its uri parameter.But I am not able to see the exact url requested.Is there any method to do the same with having all the permissions and controlled environment.

Comment: you need to be a bit more specific.  Which header in what sort of request?  when you say connect request, it makes people think of the CONNECT method, used for https tunneling.  Usually you don't get referrers in CONNECT messages, so I would expect you are not going to see URLs in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see the URI unless you do a SSL interception at proxy level. SSL interception means the proxy will terminate the SSL session with the user using an emulated digital certificate (Which the user application should be configured to trust) then the proxy server would open a new SSL session with the upstream server.
When you implement this, you would be able to see the rest of the original request and response headers and their value.